Exception Error when i run my javafx project
I am still a beginner in javafx and I have this error in my project, even though it was working correctly, but when I made some modifications using scene builder, this error appeared
My main.java

package almalah;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class AlMalah extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));


//        FXMLLoader fxmlloader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));


//        fxmlloader.setRoot(new AnchorPane());


//        Parent root=fxmlloader.load();


        stage.setTitle("Load Size Program");


        Scene scene = new Scene(root,500,600);


        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Al-malah-style.css").toExternalForm());


        stage.getIcons().add(new Image("images/ww.jpg"));


        stage.setScene(scene);


        stage.show();


    }





    /**


     * @param args the command line arguments


     */


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        launch(args);


    }


my FXML file:
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>



<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="588.0" prefWidth="455.0" stylesheets="@Al-malah-style.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="almalah.FXMLDocumentController">

    <children>

        <Button fx:id="btn2" layoutX="80.0" layoutY="374.0" onAction="#clearbtn" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="65.0" text="clear" textFill="#fcfc00">

         <font>

            <Font name="Arial Bold Italic" size="12.0" />

         </font>

      </Button>

      <Button fx:id="btn1" layoutX="337.0" layoutY="374.0" onAction="#test" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="65.0" text="Test" textFill="#eded07">

         <font>

            <Font name="Arial Bold Italic" size="12.0" />

         </font>

      </Button>

      <Label layoutX="52.0" layoutY="311.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="108.0" text="Load Size" textFill="#e80000">

         <font>

            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />

         </font>

      </Label>

      <Label layoutX="295.0" layoutY="311.0" text="Over All Size" textFill="#de0404">

         <font>

            <Font name="Arial Bold" size="18.0" />

         </font>

      </Label>

      <TextField fx:id="load_fld" layoutX="52.0" layoutY="336.0" />

      <TextField fx:id="over_fld" layoutX="295.0" layoutY="336.0" />

      <TextField fx:id="result_fld" layoutX="167.0" layoutY="432.0" />

    </children>

</AnchorPane>


and my controller:


/*


 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.


 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates


 * and open the template in the editor.


 */


package almalah;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    Button btn1=new Button();
    @FXML
    Button btn2=new Button();
    @FXML
    TextField load_fld=new TextField();
    @FXML
    TextField over_fld=new TextField();
    @FXML
    TextField result_fld=new TextField();
    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    public void clearbtn(ActionEvent event) {


        load_fld.clear();


        over_fld.clear();


        result_fld.clear();


        


    }


    


    @FXML


    public void test(ActionEvent event)


    {


        


            


        


            


        if(over_fld.getText().isEmpty() || load_fld.getText().isEmpty() )


        {


            int x=Integer.parseInt(over_fld.getText());


        int y=Integer.parseInt(load_fld.getText());


            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);


            alert.setTitle("hdghdg");


            alert.setHeaderText("hdgdh");


            alert.setContentText("hgd");


            alert.showAndWait();


            


        }


        else


        {


//        int z=x/y;


//        result_fld.setText(String.valueOf(z));


        }


        


    }


    


    @Override


    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {


        // TODO


    }    


    


}

and the error is:


java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException


    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)


    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)


    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)


    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)


    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)


    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)


    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)


    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)


    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)


    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)


    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)


Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method


    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)


    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)


    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root value already specified.


file:/C:/Users/AB%20RAMMA7/Documents/NetBeansProjects/AlMalah/dist/AlMalah.jar!/almalah/FXMLDocument.fxml





    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)


    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.createElement(FXMLLoader.java:2755)


    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2704)


    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)


    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)


    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)


    at almalah.AlMalah.start(AlMalah.java:27)


    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)


    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)


    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)


    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)


    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)


    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)


    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)


    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)


    ... 1 more


Exception running application almalah.AlMalah


C:\Users\AB RAMMA7\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AlMalah\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1052: The following error occurred while executing this line:


C:\Users\AB RAMMA7\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AlMalah\nbproject\build-impl.xml:806: Java returned: 1


BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)

Maybe the problem is in FXMLLOADER, but I am still a beginner and do not know the solution, so please help
Maybe the problem is in FXMLLOADER, but I am still a beginner and do not know the solution, so please help

Please edit the question and remove all of the unnecessary double spacing.

Your code, as provided, will not emit that error. You've commented out the problematic code. As for why that error would occur,  you can't set the loader's root unless you're using fx:root in the FXML file.

Button btn1=new Button(); type stuff is incorrect. For FXML nodes, all you have to do is  @FXML     Button btn1
